# MySQL slow query log to identify queries that scan tables

Tags: mysql, performance, execution-plan, log, query-performance

MySQL seems not to have setting to show you queries that use SOME indexes but still also do table scans

We have some badly performing queries and were hoping to find them systematically but the `log_queries_not_using_indexes` setting seems only to look for queries that use NO INDEXES AT ALL, rather than using full table scans.

Anyone to confirm? Is there a new option coming?

Answer (score 2):

I find `log_queries_not_using_indexes` to be useless.  More useful is the queries that take a long time; this will *include* any queries that do some or all table scans *and* are slow, but *exclude* trivial table scans *that are fast*.

If a table has 5 rows, it does not really matter whether it uses an index or does a table scan -- the speed will be virtually the same.

These start with the most important queries to work on.  I suggest you work on the first 3, then wait for the impact to happen and get new slowlog:

```
mysqldumpslow -s t   # to sort by most impact first
pt-query-digest
```

Also, `long_query_time=1` is probably a good starting point.

(I keep my ear to the ground; I have not heard of the option you suggest.  You *could* file a "feature request" with bugs.mysql.com.)

**More**

The Optimizer sometimes decides that a table scan is likely to be faster than using an index.  This happens when it estimates that more than 20% of the rows will be touched.  (The "20" varies with the phases of the moon.)  This is because of bouncing between the BTree of a secondary index and the data BTree has some cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable slow query log to get more details on slow queries.

```
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file="queries-slow.log"
min_examined_row_limit=5000
```

The last setting, please tweak number of rows per your requirements. Start with a high number and reduce gradually. These settings can also be set using `set global`.  In the log file you will see how many rows of a table being scanned.  If the number is close to total number of records in the table, its a full table scan.  This will allow you to pin point which queries are causing excessive number of rows being scanned.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the documentation for [MySQL 5.7 - 5.4.5 The Slow Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) is concerned...

> To include queries that do not use indexes for row lookups in the statements written to the slow query log, enable the `log_queries_not_using_indexes` system variable.

... [and](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_queries_not_using_indexes)

> `log_queries_not_using_indexes`
>
> Whether queries that do not use indexes are logged to the slow query log. See Section 5.4.5, “The Slow Query Log”.

There is **no** mention to anything related to `log_queries_using_table_scans`, or anything similar. There are not mentions either in the [Docs for MySQL 8 - 5.1.5 Server System Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html).

So, I'm afraid the answer is *no*, there is not an option coming (at least, as documented up until now). So, my guess is that you will have to log *all* slow queries, and find out later which ones do some table scans and which ones do not.

The [`mysqldumpslow`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldumpslow.html) utility might prove helpful. See also [MySQL Slow Query Log: Tools and Tips](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/03/14/mysql-slow-query-log-tools-and-tips/) and [Tools for parsing a slow query log](https://docs.acquia.com/articles/tools-parsing-slow-query-log).